# How should one interpret the minhash error rate?

Tags: algorithms, natural-language-processing, classification

On Wikipedia the error rate for the minhash algorithm vs baseline jaccard similarity [is stated as `1/sqrt(1/hashes)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash#Algorithm).

But, how should one interpret this number in a practical scenario? It seems to me that this must mean `avg(abs(minhash_similarity - jaccard_similarity))` rather than classification error, because classification would require an actual threshold. But in that case, the distribution of those errors would seem important.

To illustrate my concern, the resulting classification error for a given threshold if a 10% similarity error is uniformly distributed vs if 1/10 samples account for all of the error is 10% vs 1%.